Accessing AWS RDS using IAM Authentication with Spring DataSource
My Query is very similar to this slack post - Accessing AWS RDS using IAM Authentication and Spring JDBC (DataSource and JdbcTemplate)
I tried the following:
Add the following dependencies:
runtimeOnly 'software.aws.rds:aws-mysql-jdbc:1.1.6'
runtimeOnly 'software.amazon.awssdk:rds:2.20.57'

Add the following to application.yml:
spring:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql:aws://yourdbcluster-xxxx.cluster-xxxx.your-region.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/yourdb?useAwsIam=true
    username: iam_username
    #password: dont-need-this
    driver-class-name: software.aws.rds.jdbc.mysql.Driver

The driver uses the AWS default credentials provider chain so make sure you have credentials with policy allowing IAM DB access available wherever you are running your app -
To check if the application running on Amazon ECS has the necessary AWS credentials with a policy allowing IAM DB access, I followed these steps:
aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name ROLE_NAME
aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn POLICY_ARN --version-id v1
In the policy details, verified there is a statement allowing the rds-db:connect action.

But still the application is throwing : Access denied for the user and not able to create the bean liquidbase.
Is there any other changes required? Please suggest

The database user must be created and given the rds_iam role (in the case of Postgres); I think it should be similar in MySQL.
